# Настройка Apache: ошибка 403

Tags: apache

Написал вот такой конфиг. Почему-то в итоге вылетает 403. Как исправить?

```
<VirtualHost paint.web:80>
  ServerAdmin dan@paint.web
  ServerRoot /home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web
  DocumentRoot /home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web
  <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/uhome/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web/cgi-bin">
          AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        Alias /doc/ "/home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web/doc/"
        <Directory "/home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web/doc/">
          Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from *
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

p.s. дистрибутив - linux mint

Answer (score 1):

```
<Directory "/uhome/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web/cgi-bin"> // вместо uhome наверное просто home    AllowOverride None    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch    Order allow,deny    Allow from all</Directory>
```

не проще ли все такие вот настройки вынести в htaccess?

```
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks    AllowOverride None    Order deny,allow    Deny from all    Allow from *
```

И вот решение вопроса

```
Order deny,allow    Deny from all    Allow from *
```

Если это не идиотизм то бросьте в меня камень!

Звучат строки так. Запретить всем, разрешить всем! вот и 403 ошибка вылетает из-за доступа. **Апачь тебя не понимает! Ты либо дай доступ, либо не давай!**

Comment: сделал так:    <Directory "/home/danpetruk/Dropbox/paint.web/doc/">        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks        AllowOverride None        Order deny,allow        Allow from *    </Directory>Всё равно 403

Answer (score 0):

Очень может быть что ты просто не попадаешь на свой VirtualHost

Апач точно может отрезолвить <VirtualHost paint.web:80>

покажи вывод nslookup paint.web или dig paint.web на хосте на котором запущен апач

И если тебе не нужно ограничивать доступ то делается

Order allow,deny

Allow from all